# Include Column Names along with data in SELECT query to datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have a stored procedure which creates a temp table, populates, pivots the data and returns the lot to a datatable in my application

The outcome is that this information will be placed in a report and opened by Excel. But when the information is returned there are no column names, just the data within the table.

Is there anyway to include the column names so that they are returned along with the results to the datatable?

I am using SQL Server 2012 with SSMS

Here's the bulk of my stored procedure, for the record the number of columns can vary depending on specific conditions, so I can't hard-code the majority of column names in my application.

**Stored Procedure pivot code**

```
SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','')
           +QUOTENAME(ChargeName)
    FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT ChargeName FROM ##chargesTable) AS ChargeName

     SET @DynamicPivotQuery =
    'SELECT MemberID, FirstName, Surname, CategoryName, TotalAmount, ' + @ColumnName +  
    ' FROM ##chargesTable
        PIVOT(MIN(ChargeAmount)
            FOR ChargeName IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PivotTable
    ORDER BY MemberID'
```

**Table Output**

And this is the output of the table, I don't know what the column names will be from "TotalAmount" onwards

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out `DataTable.Columns`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the problem I think lies within SQL, the DataTable receives the information correctly and displays it in how I want, but with no column names. I was looking for a way to include the column names with the data I'm returning from SQL, if that's possible?

Comment: Since you know them (as you should) when you build your select you can always push them in as string constants along with the columns; that way they will return in the result set..: Select ID, "ID" as IDname,..

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a wee look at this. I'm currently working on adding columns to the DataTable within the program, it's a tad more complex than I thought it would be (where I thought you could just return the column names along with the data). I'll update my answer later on when I have a solution

Comment: Why are you using a global temp table? This can wreak havoc with concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Hi, I have managed to overcome this, it turns out that the column headers were being returned to the datatable after all, they weren't just being displayed in my application. I have since been able to solve this. Thanks